# How to disable "defaultHostnameVerifier" property in SpringXD

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, spring-xd

I have a requirement to connect to a https URL from my processor module when a message is put on a Q (suppose q name here is: readFromQ) and then just log the response from the url GET call. I am using http-client processor for making a GET call to the url here.
My stream looks like below :

stream create --name hitSSL --definition "jms --destination=readFromQ | http-client --url='''https://remoteHost:remotePort/trafficcontrol/'''
--httpMethod=GET | log"

Now the problem is that this URL presents spring-xd with a certificate that does not match with the hostname I am trying to hit. The certificate is named something like abc.mycompany.com, whereas the URL's hostname is remoteHost.

Spring XD throws :
**java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching remoteHost found**.

My cacerts does have the abc.mycompany.com certificate added.

I need to know if there is a way I can disable SpringXD from verifying hostname with CN while establishing SSL connection.
Is there a way to disable the java property **javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier**

**Note : I can successfully do a GET on the above URL with "http"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to override the hostname verification. Thanks to folks in my team.

I updated my xd-admin and xd-container scripts to have :

**DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-javaagent:/opt/spring-xd-1.1.0.M1/xd/lib/HostnameVerifier.jar**

This HostnameVerifier.jar is a javaagent which overrides the verify method in setDefaultHostnameVerifier property as below :

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
    {
      public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession)
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Now SpringXD does not complain where the host to connect to and the server name from the certificate mismatch.